# Pipe output from Dockerfile RUN command to host

Tags: docker

I have the following image:

```
FROM some:image

ADD app /app

ADD https://get.aquasec.com/microscanner /
RUN chmod +x /microscanner
RUN /microscanner my_xxx_token >> /microscan.log
```

the `RUN /microscanner` command outputs a bunch of stuff. If I don't `>>` pipe it to a file, it's gonna be printed to my console.

What I want is to pipe it directly to the host, because the command, if having a false result, interrupts the build of the image, so I cannot execute any other Docker commands after it. Even a `&& cat /microscan.log` on the same `RUN` command after the microscanner will not execute.

I tried doing `>> /app/microscanner.log` since the folder is used as a shared volume, but the file doesn't appear on the host.

So, I assume that I have to write from the container directly into a file on the host. Is that a possibility at all?

Comment: Why is it important to run this in a Dockerfile?  Why is it important to run it in Docker at all?

Comment: This is not the right way to do the things, I guess you should use ENTRYPOINT to run the script while docker run command and your script should write the logs to a file in the container and you should have mounted the host directory with the container. In this way, you will be able to see the logs file on host generated in the container.